# Mutating values of a column to keep only the numbers in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling, grepl

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
example <- data.frame(
  subject = c('sub-137', 'sub-138', 'sub-139')
)
```

How can I mutate the `subject` column such that only the numbers remain? This is the desired output:

```
example_solution <- data.frame(
  subject = c(137, 138, 139)
)
```

Thank you!

Comment: `mutate(example, subject = readr::parse_number(subject))` is one way. See the marked duplicate for more options.

Comment: @GregorThomas - I think that will give the *negative* numbers. Here we need to discard the `-`.

Comment: @DanAdams plenty of other options at the marked dupe - many of which ignore `-`. Or wrap in `abs()`.

Comment: @GregorThomas - you're right, this is an obvious dupe. Just being a pedant.